# Setting up multiple Kernels in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, multisite, symfony-kernel

I am trying to set up a multi-site architecture in Symfony 4 using multiple Kernels.

It would be too lengthy to post all of the changes I have made but I basically followed the [Symfony docs for creating a new Kernel](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/multiple_kernels.html) and the changes I made can be viewed in the following [pull request](https://github.com/yevgetman/symfony-multi/pull/1/files).

When I attempt to run the api kernel locally (`php bin/api server:run`) I get the following error message:

[image: Error Message]

I am simply trying to load the home controller and template using the new Kernel

```
# config/api/routes.yaml

home:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\Home::index
```

Comment: Double check where routes.yaml is being loaded.  looks like you have it loaded under configureContainer instead of configureRoutes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Place `routes.yaml` under `config/routes` directory, otherwise Symfony treats this file as a framework configuration file.
2. Or you can reconfigure kernel to load routes files from `api` directory by editig `configureContainer` and `configureRoutes` methods of `ApiKernel`.

Comment: thank you! I think (2) is more what Im looking for - such that I can completely encapsulate an application, including its routes. what changes would I make to `configureContainer` and `configureRoutes` methods?